# Android: смена id в ListView

Tags: getview, android, listview, java, adapter

Здравствуйте! Возникла такая проблема, хотя наверное это не проблема, а просто пока не привык к `Java` и `Android` в целом. 
У меня есть `ListView` в который я гружу данные:

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> circles2 = getCircles(); 
String[] columns = new String[] { "id", "name" };
int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, circles2,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, columns, to); 
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

После чего при нажатии на item, обрабатываю событие:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      Log.d(TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = " + id);
   }
});
```

В лог мне падает следующее:

```
10-02 16:47:44.861  23467/framework D/CirclesActivity: itemClick: position = 0, id = 0
10-02 16:47:47.049  23467/framework D/CirclesActivity: itemClick: position = 1, id = 1
10-02 16:47:48.291  23467/framework D/CirclesActivity: itemClick: position = 2, id = 2
```

Мне необходимо сделать так, что бы при нажатии на item, в id был идентификатор круга, который лежит в списке circles2. Я искал информацию на эту тему, нашел что можно сделать CustomAdapter расширив класс ArrayAdapter. Ок, я сделал как было написано, но всё равно результат меня не удовлетворяет, id остался прежним и мой id не подставляется.

Код адаптера на [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/nVWjf6F2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, что бы возвращался именно ваш id, нужно у CustomAdapter переопределить так же метод `getItemId()`  
Выглядит это примерно так

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).id;
}
```

Или можно "вручную" определить ID нажатого элемента.  
для этого: 
`int id = adapter.getItem(position).id;`

Answer (score 3):

Переопределите в адаптере метод `getItemId()` и возвращайте в нём нужные вам значения `id`.